# Conditional large() using array in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm using an array formula to calculate the second-largest value in each of Columns B-Z, conditional on the values being with a certain date range in Column A. Cells J2 and J3 contain the date ranges for IF function.

The formula I'm using is as follows:

```
{=LARGE(IF(($A$4:$A$4054>=$J$2)*($A$4:$A$4054<=$J$3),B4:B4054),2))}
```

In the majority of cases, the formula works perfectly but occasionally it is throwing up "0" as the answer - even though there's no zeroes in column D.

Is there an error with the formula? Or, alternatively, is there another formula I can use to achieve the same outcome?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: is it possible that there is 0 or 1 value within the dates required?

Comment: Wow, you're a genius (not being sarcastic). Some of Columns B-Z had blank cells but Column A would still have a date value - getting rid of the date values in Column A that corresponded to blank cells solved the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: good to be of service... try using the evaluate formula, i think it might have help on this one. Although I know from personal experience it is challenging to use with array formulas.

Comment: I tried that but with 4,000 for ~400 columns it was a bit tiresome!